# java.lang.NullPointerException in Firebase Realtime Database fetching activity

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have beenn struggling to find out why I am getting the error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Below is the full description of the error:

> 2021-03-15 14:15:49.906 24447-24447/com.goldencrestit.quicky2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> 2021-03-15 14:15:49.907 24447-24447/com.goldencrestit.quicky2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.goldencrestit.quicky2, PID: 24447
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
> at com.goldencrestit.quicky2.ViewProfileActivity$1.onDataChange(ViewProfileActivity.java:64)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7581)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)

This error pops up when I click on the "View your Profile" button in order to load the profile page.

[image: Job Portal Image]

Below is the expected result. It is support to fetch data from my firebase realtime database to fill the dummy texts:

[image: Job Detail Image]

Check below my codes:

**activity_company_portal.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/bg_color"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".CompanyPortal">
    
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_home" />
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/logout_btn"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_power_settings_new_24" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
    
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20dp">
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/view_job"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:letterSpacing=".2"
                android:text="@string/view_all_jobs" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_job"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
                android:layout_below="@id/view_job"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:letterSpacing=".2"
                android:text="@string/add_a_new_job" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
                android:layout_below="@id/add_job"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:letterSpacing=".2"
                android:text="@string/edit_your_profile" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/view_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
                android:layout_below="@id/edit_profile"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:letterSpacing=".2"
                android:text="@string/view_your_profile" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**CompanyPortalActivity.java**

```
    public class CompanyPortalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_company_portal);
    
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_home);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Quicky Job Portal");
    
            Button viewJobs = findViewById(R.id.view_job);
            Button postJobs = findViewById(R.id.add_job);
            Button edit_profile = findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
            Button view_profile = findViewById(R.id.view_profile);
    
    
            viewJobs.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IndividualPostActivity.class)));
    
            postJobs.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostJobsActivity.class)));
    
            edit_profile.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditProfileActivity.class)));
    
            view_profile.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewProfileActivity.class)));
    
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    
            ImageButton mLogoutBtn = findViewById(R.id.logout_btn);
    
            mLogoutBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    
                mAuth.signOut();
                sendUserToLogin();
    
            });
        }
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if(mCurrentUser == null){
                sendUserToLogin();
            }
        }
    
        private void sendUserToLogin() {
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CompanyLoginActivity.class);
            loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

**activity_view_profile.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/bg_color"
        tools:context=".ViewProfileActivity">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_primary"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:text="Company Name" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/company_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
                android:text="Golden Crest Tech"
                android:background="@drawable/text_display" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_primary"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:text="Business Type" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/business_type"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
                android:text="Technology"
                android:background="@drawable/text_display" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_primary"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:text="Phone Number" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
                android:text="08020345678"
                android:background="@drawable/text_display" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_primary"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:text="Company Address" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
                android:text="Surulere, Lagos"
                android:background="@drawable/text_display" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_primary"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Company Detail" />
    
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextTextMultiLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/text_display_2"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:text="@string/company_detail_dummy"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Edit Profile" />
    
    
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**ViewProfileActivity.java**

```
    public class ViewProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private DatabaseReference myRef;
    
        TextView company_name_txt, business_type_txt, phone_number_txt, company_address_txt;
        EditText company_detail_txt;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_profile);
    
            company_name_txt = findViewById(R.id.company_name);
            business_type_txt = findViewById(R.id.business_type);
            phone_number_txt = findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            company_address_txt = findViewById(R.id.address);
            company_detail_txt = findViewById(R.id.company_detail);
    
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Company Profile");
            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Company Profile");
            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()){
                        String companyName = snapshot.child("company_name").getValue().toString();
                        String phoneNumber = snapshot.child("phone_number").getValue().toString();
                        String companyAddress= snapshot.child("address").getValue().toString();
                        String businessType = snapshot.child("business_type").getValue().toString();
    
                        company_name_txt.setText(companyName);
                        business_type_txt.setText(businessType);
                        company_address_txt.setText(companyAddress);
                        phone_number_txt.setText(phoneNumber);
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
                finish();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Below is what I am trying to display on the Job Detail Layout:

[image: Realtime Database on Firebase]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to come from this piece of code:

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Company Profile");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
            String companyName = snapshot.child("company_name").getValue().toString();
            String phoneNumber = snapshot.child("phone_number").getValue().toString();
            String companyAddress= snapshot.child("address").getValue().toString();
            String businessType = snapshot.child("business_type").getValue().toString();

            company_name_txt.setText(companyName);
            business_type_txt.setText(businessType);
            company_address_txt.setText(companyAddress);
            phone_number_txt.setText(phoneNumber);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
});
```

The above code is loading all data from `/Company Profile` and then trying to read the `company_name` property from it. But if we look at the data you shared, there is no `/Company Profile/company_name` property, so that explains why `getValue()` returns `null` and the `toString()` then leads to the exception you get.

It seems your JSON tree consists of: `/Company Profile/$uid/$pushid`. How to property load the data from this structure depends on how much information you already know in your code, so let's look at the options:

---

**If you know both the UID and the push ID of the information you want to load**, you can do load just that with:

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Company Profile");
String uid = "6babpG...MxLg33"; // must be the exact, complete value
String pushid = "-MVmyqx...3rwsAO"; // must be the exact, complete value
myRef.child(uid).child(pushid().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
            String companyName = snapshot.child("company_name").getValue().toString();
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

---

**If you know the UID, but not the push ID, of the information you want to load**, you can load all push IDs and loop over them with:

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Company Profile");
String uid = "6babpG...MxLg33"; // must be the exact, complete value
myRef.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String companyName = snapshot.child("company_name").getValue().toString();
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

So here we loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` to get across the unknown push IDs from the database. This means we can have multiple child nodes, so you may want to consider using a list view/recycler view for displaying the data.

---

The final case is if you **know neither the UID nor the push ID of the data you want to display**. In that case you need two nested loops to navigate over the data, one for the UIDs in the JSON, and one for the push IDs. So:

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Company Profile");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String companyName = snapshot.child("company_name").getValue().toString();
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

You'll note that the solution is quite similar to the previous one, but now with a second loop. Here too, you'll have to consider what is the best UI element to display the structure, as now you're navigating/parsing an entire tree-like structure from the database.

Comment: This works for me and I was able to get the uId using the getUid() function but I could not get the push ID. Is there function that will get me a specific push ID so that I won't have to copy it from the database the way it is. I just want to assume I do not have access to database.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. a push ID is generated when you call `push()` and then write data to that new location. If you need the push elsewhere too, you should store it there when you first generate it. If you don't need a push ID in your data structure, you shouldn't call `push()` in your code.

Comment: I removed the push() function and it is solved.